# How to make the promise defined

Tags: angularjs

Here is my code of saving the Orders data but while saving promise undefined. So how to make the data as promising defined.

```
factmodule.factory("OrderApiFactory",function($resource,$q){

var OrderInf=[];
var OrderInfResource=$resource("http://demo.foodzard.in/api/order")
return{

   PushApiOrder:function(totlist){


       var list=new OrderInfResource(totlist)

       list.$save(function(infdata){

           console.log(infdata)
           OrderInf.push(infdata);
       },function(inf){
           console.log("Error while saving the data");
       });

       }

   }
```

please help me.

Comment: There a several problems with your code. What error message are you getting? That should point out one of your problems.

Comment: there is no error message. but promise undefined like this.Resource {message: "Inserted Successfully", $promise: undefined, $resolved: true}